# Export keywords in file.gz

Tags: php, export, keyword

I have a xxx.gz file, it content some text characters below:

```
Array
(
[f_name] => YOKICHI
[l_name] => KOSHIZAWA
[name] => YOKICHI KOSHIZAWA
[street_address] => 7164 fake
[city] => CANTON
[state] => MI
[zip] => 48187
[country] => United States
[phone] => 734-354-6599
[email] => ykoshizawxxa@att.net
[discount_percent] => 0.00
[discount_amount] => 0
[discount_items] => 
[shipping_region] => USA
[shipping_type] => 
[shipping_priority] => 
[shipping_options] => 
[shipping_total] => 0
)
```

I need a PHP source code to running on local host, can filter then export information below:

```
| f_name | l_name | street_address | city | state | zip | phone | country
```

for example:

```
| YOKICHI | KOSHIZAWA | 7164 fake | CANTON | MI | 48187 | 734-354-6567 | United States
```

Comment: Have a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php no one is going to write a regex for you...

Comment: @IshayPeled Using regular expressions is probably not a good idea, if the data could change, for example if nested arrays are added. You'd better use some tool able to parse context free languages.

Comment: @Jost that seems like an overkill for the task at hand (;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the code for you, don't just copy this, try to learn with it :)

```
// $source = file_get_contents($file);
$source = 'Array
(
[f_name] => YOKICHI
[l_name] => KOSHIZAWA
[name] => YOKICHI KOSHIZAWA
[street_address] => 7164 fake
[city] => CANTON
[state] => MI
[zip] => 48187
[country] => United States
[phone] => 734-354-6599
[email] => ykoshizawxxa@att.net
[discount_percent] => 0.00
[discount_amount] => 0
[discount_items] => 
[shipping_region] => USA
[shipping_type] => 
[shipping_priority] => 
[shipping_options] => 
[shipping_total] => 0
)';

// convert input to array
$arr = explode(PHP_EOL, $source);

// clean top and bottom of the array
array_shift($arr);
array_shift($arr);
array_pop($arr);

// init final array
$final = array();

foreach($arr as $v)
{
    $o = array();
    $v = preg_match_all('#\[([a-zA-Z0-9 _.-]+)\] => (.*)#', $v, $o);

    $key = $o[1][0];
    $val = (isset($o[2][0])) ? $o[2][0] : ''; 

    // fill final
    $final[$key] = $val;
}

// init the filtered array
$sort = array();
// keys you want to have in
$keys = array('f_name','l_name','street_address','city','state','zip','phone','country');

foreach($final as $k => $v)
{
    if(in_array($k, $keys))
    {
        $sort[$k] = $v;
    }
}

var_dump($sort);
```

Comment: Thank you for good code, but it display is:  array(8) { ["f_name"]=> string(7) "YOKICHI" ["l_name"]=> string(9) "KOSHIZAWA" ["street_address"]=> string(9) "7164 fake" ["city"]=> string(6) "CANTON" ["state"]=> string(2) "MI" ["zip"]=> string(5) "48187" ["country"]=> string(13) "United States" ["phone"]=> string(12) "734-354-6599" }  ...... You can help me with | YOKICHI | KOSHIZAWA | 7164 fake | CANTON | MI | 48187 | 734-354-6567 | United States

Comment: Ok good..........i only edit :     if(in_array($k, $keys))
    {
        $sort[$k] = $v;
        echo " | ".$v;
    }

Comment: Well it looks your server isnt configured to show nicely the var_dumps, you can replace `var_dump($sort);` by `echo '<pre>'; print_r($sort); echo '</pre>';`